# Stream filter returns NullPointerException in condition

Tags: java, android

I have a condition that does not work due to `NullPointerException`. This is my code:

```
public class RightDrawerItem {

    User user;
    String sectionName, title, subitle, subtitle2;
    int amount, icon;
    boolean expanded;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setSectionName(String sectionName) {
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

    public String getSubitle() {
        return subitle;
    }

    public void setSubitle(String subitle) {
        this.subitle = subitle;
    }

    public String getSubtitle2() {
        return subtitle2;
    }

    public void setSubtitle2(String subtitle2) {
        this.subtitle2 = subtitle2;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getSectionName() {
        return sectionName;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }


    public static class Builder {

        private String sectionName, title;
        private final int amount;
        boolean expanded;
        private int icon;
        private User user;

        public Builder(int amount) {
            this.expanded = false;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public Builder title(String title) {
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder icon(int icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder sectionName(String sectionName) {
            this.sectionName = sectionName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder user(User user) {
            this.user = user;
            return this;
        }

        public RightDrawerItem build() {
            return new RightDrawerItem(this);
        }
    }

    public RightDrawerItem(Builder builder) {
        this.title = builder.title;
        this.icon = builder.icon;
        this.amount = builder.amount;
        this.sectionName = builder.sectionName;
        this.user = builder.user;
    }
}
```

Here is my `User` class:

```
public class User {

String name;
int level, exp, gold;
Timestamp regDate;

public Timestamp getRegDate() {
    return regDate;
}

public void setRegDate(Timestamp regDate) {
    this.regDate = regDate;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(int level) {
    this.level = level;
}

public int getExp() {
    return exp;
}

public void setExp(int exp) {
    this.exp = exp;
}

public int getGold() {
    return gold;
}

public void setGold(int gold) {
    this.gold = gold;
}

public User(String name, int level, int exp, int gold, Timestamp regDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.exp = exp;
    this.gold = gold;
    this.regDate = regDate;
}
```

}

And here is my condition code in `SearchAdapter`:

```
List<RightDrawerItem> rightDrawerItems;
List<User> users;

...

if (!Stream.of(rightDrawerItems).filter(o -> o.getTitle() != null).anyMatch(o -> o.getTitle().equals(users.get(pos).getName())))
```

The problem is that this `.filter` seems not to work because `.anyMatch` finds sometimes such elements which `getTitle()` returns `null`. How to solve it?

Comment: Yes. `filter` means 'keep' or 'retain' here, and not 'filter out'.

Comment: Okay I changed to .filter(o -> o.getTitle() != null) and nothing changed. Still get " java.lang.String pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.other.RightDrawerItem.getTitle()' on a null object reference"

Comment: `filter` keeps the elements matching the predicate, it does not remove them - see the JavaDocs of [Stream.filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)): "Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate."

Comment: Ok then how can I fix this condition?

Comment: Well, look at the line that caused the NPE: `o.getTitle().equals(users.get(pos).getName())`. Dereferencing `null` via `.` (aka `someNull.operation()`) will cause an NPE. You've already confirmed that `o.getTitle()` isn't null in the filter, so `o.getTitle().equals(...)` won't NPE (unless your #equals throws an NPE on a null value given to it). So out of what's left: `users.get(pos).getName()` which of those pieces (before a `.`) do you think could be `null`? Aka do you think `users.get(pos)` is null? or is `users` null?

Answer (score 1):

The Exception states that `o` itself is null, so you can't call `null.getTitle()`. You can add `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` to 'skip' those in your check:

```
if (Stream.of(rightDrawerItems) //note the removed
           .filter(Objects::nonNull) // <- avoid Exceptions due to o==null
           .filter(o -> o.getTitle() != null)
           .anyMatch(o -> o.getTitle().equals(users.get(pos).getName()))
   )
```

But it may be advisable to figure out why some of your rightDrawerItems could be null in the first place.

A neater way of writing the above could also be:

```
    if (Stream.of(rightDrawerItems)           //note the removed negation (noneMatch below)
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)          // <- avoid Exceptions due to o==null
           .map(RightDrawerItem::getTitle)    //we're interested in the title
           .noneMatch(users.get(pos).getName()::equals)   //use noneMatch
   )
```

Comment: Items for rightDrawerItems are made of Builder where I can choose which properties to be instantiated and it is all deliberate that some properties are null or 0 due to further logic. In this case I don't set title for a few items, they have anoher properties set. Accordung to your answer, I was trying .filter(Objects::nonNull) but the same - NPE.

Comment: Then I would suggest you either use a debugger to step through the execution to figure out what trips the Exception (in any decent IDE you can add a breakpoint on NPE being thrown), and/or add some debug print statements that will allow you to figure out what triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Stream.of(rightDrawerItems).filter(o -> o != null).filter(o -> o.getTitle() != null).anyMatch(o -> o.getTitle().equals(users.get(pos).getName())))
```

solves my problem.

Comment: To be honest that is exactly what I told you to do :-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/64713657/9569292
`Objects::nonNull` is a built in, nicer-to-read equivalent to your `o -> o != null`